# MacOS SSH Server how to find password

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh

I wish to start an ssh server on my mac, so I did the following:

System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login -> on

I ran the ssh service using `sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on`

I then tried to ssh into the machine from a different computer on the same local network using the command `ssh username@username.local` and it then asked me for a password. I tried inputting the sudo password of the mac but that was not right.

My config files are as below:

**ssh_config**

```
# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org)
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

**sshd_config**

```
# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://xquartz.macosforge.org)
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Maybe a mistake in `username`? The password is supposed to be your usual session password... Besides, you don' t need `sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on`

Comment: @PierU usual session password, do you mean like my macbook login password that i use to open the laptop? It gives the exact ssh command with the username preset even, and I just use that and it doesn't work

Comment: You’re not actually using “username” in that SSH command, right?  You’re using your actual Mac username, right?  If so, then the password is your Mac password.

Comment: @jimtut I am using my own mac username, and the password did not work with my mac password. nevertheless I have fixed it now, the issue was related to a missing authorized_keys file in my ssh folder where I put the pubkeys for the ssh addresses i wanted to use

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have a file called `authorized_keys` that has the public key content of whatever keys you want to use in it, one per line, like so:

```
rsa etiohn3w05hn30prinhwrhnw30ringw30rign3w0irn35r0ihn3 username@blabla
rsa etiohn3w05hn30prinhwrhnw30ringw30rign3w0irn35r0ihn3 username@blabla
```

Comment: That's weird... As far as I know `authorized_keys` is needed when one want to connect without a password. If it's missing it's still possible to connect with a password (unless the ssh server is configured to deny password-based connection, but by default the password-based connection is authorized on macOS).

Comment: @PierU I am aware, but no matter which passwords I attempted none of them worked. I ran `ssh-keygen -A` which should remove the passwords and set it to nothing, but that did not work either. only thing that worked was above

Comment: I tried removing the `authorized_keys` file and was still able to connect with a password. Also, `ssh-keygen -A` is not supposed to "remove the passwords" (?)... I don't quite understand what you are doing.

Comment: @PierU Don't worry, the problem is fixed. I am likely doing something wrong, but regardless the method above works